# Count number of lines that are not comment or are not blank in a file

Tags: python

I am trying to count the number of SLOC using the following code but it is not working it is just printing 0 can someone please help

```
f = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Rental.java", "r")

#print(f.read())
for l in f:
  count=0
  if (l.strip() and l.startswith('/')):
      count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: If you're looking for lines that are *not* a comment you should be checking `not l.startswith('/')`

Comment: there are 4 issues there: 1) you're reinitializing `count` at every iteration instead of once outside of the loop.  2) you are checking for a single / instead of // which is a comment 3) you are counting comments, not SLOCs 4) you will not detect indented comments

Answer (score 1):

You reset `count` in every iteration, so you'll only ever get an answer of `0` or `1`. Instead, set it before the loop.

`l.strip()` doesn't modify `l`. Instead, it *returns a new string!* You should assign that to `l`.

Additionally, you want to count how many lines *aren't* a comment, so you need to check `not l.startswith('/')`. It might even make more sense to check `.startswith('//')` because a single forward-slash doesn't make a comment in java. In fact, something like this would be wrongly identified as having a commented line if you just do `.startswith('/')`:

```java
double a = 1.0
         / 5.0;
```

Here's your fixed code:

```
count = 0
f = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Rental.java", "r")

for l in f:
  l = l.strip()
  if l and not l.startswith('//'):
      count += 1
print(count)
```

I am ignoring the case of multiline comments using `/* ... */` since you haven't addressed it in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sum() function to get the count directly:

```
with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Rental.java", "r") as f:
    SLOC = sum(not line.startswith('//') for line in map(str.strip,f) if line)
    print(SLOC)
```

Using map(str.strip,... on the line iterator allows you to easily exclude blank lines and detect indented comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `count` before the loop.

```py
f = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Rental.java", "r")
count = 0
#print(f.read())
for l in f:
  if (l.strip() and l.startswith('/')):
      count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: This answer ignores the two other things that are wrong with OP's code.